# Can you identify this fuse?

Tags: fuses

Sorry, dumb one really. I just had the heating out for a couple of days and eventually found a fuse blown in a controller for the (LK) underfloor heating.

I can't tell what rating it has (amps). It has T200H250V embossed around the end, and is made by ESKA with an S on the bottom/top. But that doesn't Google well.

I can see that the transformer it was (presumably) protecting has an output of 2 x 20VA @ 12V, I've found a 3.15A 20mm clear-glass fuse for sale, but maybe someone on here can better guess than me?

[image: Side profile]

[image: End profile]

End of question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Literal answer to your title: Yes!

Literal answer to your actual question: No. I don't (have to) guess.

Answer to your inferred question: 250V 200mA Slow Blow, Ceramic Passivated.